# Meaning of refrain in 青空 by "The Blue Hearts"

Tags: song-lyrics

The refrain of the Blue Hearts song 青空 starts like this:

生まれた所や皮膚や目の色でいったいこの僕の何がわかるというのだろう

While the first part is rather clear, I don't understand the second part. What's the meaning of いったいこの僕？

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked up [一体]{いったい} in any dictionary? https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/3870/meaning/m0u/ → definition #3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

いったい＝一体＝the hell, on earth

> 生まれた所や皮膚や目の色で、この僕の何がわかるというのだろう

=What do they know about me with only the information such as my nationality, my skin color, or my eye color?

> 生まれた所や皮膚や目の色で、**一体**この僕の何がわかるというのだろう

=What ***the hell*** do they know about me with only the information such as my nationality, my skin color, or my eye color?

Answer (score 1):

I love the Blue Hearts! One of the greatest bands of all time :)

As Seesawscene said, いったい carries the meaning of such English expressions as, "What on earth?!" or, "What the heck?" as in this example sentence:

> 彼{かれ}が働【はたら】いているのはいったいどこか。 Where the heck does he work? [Link](http://Where%20the%20heck%20does%20he%20work?)

The next part, この僕, simply means "me" or "myself" here. Its use is somewhat lyrical here; it's not the way you would refer to yourself in everyday speech. I sometimes hear that way of speaking in old samurai movies.

I would translate the sentence to mean, "What the hell can they know about me, just based on my birthplace, skin and eye color?"

You can break it apart like this:

[image: Sentence breakdown]